# How can I get rid of fraction? (The fraction somehow still remains.)

Tags: java, floating-point

I'm trying to make a "Distance & Speed to Time"
But the fraction is obstructing me to calculate the minute part.
Like... the hour part still have a fractional value somewhere.

This is what I want.

In this example Distance is 130 km and speed is 40 km/hr

Answer I want is

```
3 Hour(s) 15 Minute(s) 0 Second(s)
```

But what I get is

```
3 Hour(s) **0 Minute(s) 0 Second(s)**
```

```
float Bx = 130;
float By = 40;
int x = (int) Bx;
int y = (int) By;
var KeepSecond = (x / y * 3600) ;
var HourX = KeepSecond/3600;

int Hour = (int) HourX;
var MinuteX = (KeepSecond-(Hour*3600))/60;
int Minute = (int) MinuteX;
var SecondX = (KeepSecond-(Hour*3600)-(Minute*60));
int Second = (int) SecondX;
String result = String.format(Hour+" Hour(s) "+Minute+" Minute(s) "+Second+" Second(s) ");
Answer.setText(result);
```

Comment: What's a *demical*?

Comment: The demical number
Like...
3.14 | .14 is demical things
And I only want [3]

Ps : My english isn't strong. If you're confused, please ask me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal

Comment: Oh sorry for my english.
I changing it right away!
Thank you a lot.

Comment: I see, I will remember that and going to use that if I'm going to do something like this again!
Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Also, I think you are abusing `String.format(String format, Object... args)`...

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'fraction'. Decimal is a radix. Unfortunately people seem to use it for decimal *places* and also the decimal *point,* which is beyond confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an int division on `distance/speed` : `130/40` gives 3 with int types

You need the double or float division of `130.0/40.0` which gives expected `3.25`

```
var KeepSecond = (Bx / By * 3600);
```

---

Also use meaningfull variable name and follow Java convention which is lowerCamelCase for variable (UpperCamelCase for class name)

```
float distance = 130;
float speed = 40;
var keepSecond = (distance / speed * 3600);

int hourInt = (int) keepSecond / 3600;
int minuteInt = (int) (keepSecond - (hourInt * 3600)) / 60;
int secondInt = (int) (keepSecond - (hourInt * 3600) - (minuteInt * 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

That intermediate casting to `int`s is the problem.

Along with removing `int x = (int) Bx; int y = (int) By;`, I would make that code a little clearer and [conventionally] correct as follows:

```
float distance = 130f;
float speed = 40f;

int secondsInMinute = 60;
int minutesInHour = 60;
int secondsInHour = minutesInHour * secondsInMinute;

int timeInSeconds = (int) (distance / speed * secondsInHour); // formula: t = d/s
int hours = timeInSeconds / secondsInHour;
int minutes = (timeInSeconds - (hours * secondsInHour)) / secondsInMinute;
int seconds = timeInSeconds - ((hours * secondsInHour) + (minutes * secondsInMinute));

String result = String.format("%d Hour(s) %d Minute(s) %d Second(s)", hours, minutes, seconds);
Answer.setText(result);
```